Java SpringBoot muestra un objeto que no es nulo, como nulo en el response
Estoy programando en springboot java, y tengo un problema. Tengo una clase (digamos Familia) con un atributo de tipo otra clase. Cuando creo el primer objeto completo los datos y todo ok,en el debug veo que todos los datos del objeto fueron añadidos. Mando el objeto al response, y resulta que en el json el atributo me sale como null.
Ejemplo ilustrativo de mi problema.
public class Familia{
private int id;
private int numero_dehijos;
private Hijo primogenito;
}
public class Hijo{
int edad;
String nombre;
Srtring esposa;
}

Cuando creo el objeto familia, y lo envio al response, el json me muestra esto.
{
  "id": "1",
  "numero_de_hijos": "2", 
  "primogenito": null;
}

Debugueando el codigo, justo antes de llamar al metodo
return new ResponseEntity<Familia>(result, HttpStatus.OK)

en el controlador; veo que dentro del objto Familia, el objeto hijo esta bien inicializado, y tiene los datos del hijo.

Tienes definidos los getters y setters para las clases?

no veo los getters y los setters ...

numero_dehijos; sería numeroDeHijos, por favor cíñete a las buenas prácticas. Pásanos un [mre], algo que podamos copiar y pegar y sirva para reproducir tu problema. De lo contrario es imposible ayudarte. Ni tienes getters ni los atributos son accesibles desde fuera de la propia clase con lo cual eso ya impediría que sea algo diferente a null. Tienes errores tipográficos en las clases Srtring no existe... con el código que nos has dado te puedo decir a ciencia cierta que NADA funciona. Cómo vamos a poder ayudarte así??

Hola Goran, bienvenido, nos muestras un ejemplo, nos dices que has instanciado bien tus objetos, pero no nos muestras el código real, algo está mal, y si no lo vemos, solo podemos conjeturar, si quieres una buena respuesta, añade el código que usas, solo la porción pertinente y como texto.

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

Como puedes leer en el código de Jackson, la manera en que esta librería detecta los campos es mediante setters y getters.
Esto es relevante porque como puedes ver en la documentación de spring, aunque soporta adicionalmente gson y json-b para conversión de objeto a json, por defecto usa jackson para serializar/deserializar objetos JSON
cómo funciona
en POJOPropertiesCollector se hace una llamada usando el api de reflexión
for (AnnotatedMethod m : _classDef.memberMethods()) {
        // For methods, handling differs between getters and setters; and
        // we will also only consider entries that either follow the bean
        // naming convention or are explicitly marked: just being visible
        // is not enough (unlike with fields)

        int argCount = m.getParameterCount();
        if (argCount == 0) { // getters (including 'any getter')
            _addGetterMethod(props, m, _annotationIntrospector);
        } else if (argCount == 1) { // setters
            _addSetterMethod(props, m, _annotationIntrospector);
        } else if (argCount == 2) { // any setter?
            if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(_annotationIntrospector.hasAnySetter(m))) {
                if (_anySetters == null) {
                    _anySetters = new LinkedList<>();
                }
                _anySetters.add(m);
            }
        }

Como verás este método trata de obtener los nombres de las propiedades siguiendo las convenciones de nombrado de la especificación JavaBeans, de la cual puedes leer más aquí.

Tengo implementado todos los getter and setter.

@Goran eso no se deja ver en tu publicacion... publicas algo a media entonces ...

@Goran de acuerdo al [mcve] que publicaste no

no soy experto en java, pero cuando Programas Orientado a Objetos (POO) es impresindible que sigas las buenas practicas, entre ellas tus clases deben contar con getters y setters para las propiedades.
Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de la clase y su implementación, lo demas ya lo tienes casi listo:
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Familia familia = new Familia();
        familia.setId(1);
        familia.setNumero_dehijos(2);

        Hijo primogenito = new Hijo();
        primogenito.setEdad(10);
        primogenito.setNombre("Juan");
        primogenito.setEsposa("Maria");

        familia.setPrimogenito(primogenito);

        
        System.out.println("Datos de la Familia:");
        System.out.println("ID: " + familia.getId());
        System.out.println("Numero de hijos: " + familia.getNumero_dehijos());
        System.out.println("Primogenito:");
        System.out.println("  Edad: " + familia.getPrimogenito().getEdad());
        System.out.println("  Nombre: " + familia.getPrimogenito().getNombre());
        System.out.println("  Esposa: " + familia.getPrimogenito().getEsposa());
    }

    static class Familia {
        private int id;
        private int numero_dehijos;
        private Hijo primogenito;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public int getNumero_dehijos() {
            return numero_dehijos;
        }

        public void setNumero_dehijos(int numero_dehijos) {
            this.numero_dehijos = numero_dehijos;
        }

        public Hijo getPrimogenito() {
            return primogenito;
        }

        public void setPrimogenito(Hijo primogenito) {
            this.primogenito = primogenito;
        }
    }

    static class Hijo {
        private int edad;
        private String nombre;
        private String esposa;

        public int getEdad() {
            return edad;
        }

        public void setEdad(int edad) {
            this.edad = edad;
        }

        public String getNombre() {
            return nombre;
        }

        public void setNombre(String nombre) {
            this.nombre = nombre;
        }

        public String getEsposa() {
            return esposa;
        }

        public void setEsposa(String esposa) {
            this.esposa = esposa;
        }
    }
}

Ahora vamos a ver una breve explicación:

Clases Familia y Hijo: Estas clases están definidas dentro de la clase principal (Main) como clases estáticas para mantener todo en un solo archivo. Cada clase tiene sus atributos privados (id, numero_dehijos, primogenito para Familia; edad, nombre, esposa para Hijo) y métodos getter y setter para acceder a estos atributos, esto quiere decir que tendrias que hacer algunos cambios para llevarlo a tu entorno implementando los namespaces que manejas.

Objeto Familia: Se crea una instancia de Familia con datos ficticios (id, numero_dehijos) y se crea también un objeto Hijo para asignarlo como primogenito de la familia.

Imprimir datos: En lugar de convertir Familia a JSON, simplemente imprimimos los datos de Familia y su primogenito en la consola. Esto muestra cómo puedes trabajar con los objetos directamente sin necesidad de usar bibliotecas externas para la serialización/deserialización. Aun asi si desean utilizar el objeto en una respuesta, puedes convertirlo a JSON.


OUTPUT de la Ejecucion del codigo de ejemplo:

